# Replacement for dupli_list and dupli_list_create

Tags: instances, dupli-groups

I am updating older work from before 2.8. The `dupli_list` and `dupli_list_create` have caught me out though and I am unsure how they were replaced. If anyone could give me some pointers to where it has changed that would be awesome. Here is the code for reference.

```
BL::BlendData::collections_iterator b_gr;   
BL::Collection::objects_iterator b_ob;

            for(b_gr->objects.begin(b_ob); b_ob != b_gr->objects.end(); ++b_ob) {
                if (b_ob->is_duplicator()) {
                    b_ob->dupli_list_create(b_scene, instance_settings);
                              //b_ob->is_modified(b_scene, instance_settings);

                              BL::BlendData::objects_iterator b_dup;

                              for(b_ob->dupli_list.begin(b_dup); b_dup != b_ob->dupli_list.end(); ++b_dup) {
```

I believe is_duplicator() becomes is_instancer(). If this is wrong then I may be further off track than I anticipated :D

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The new implementation of **Instancing in 2.8x** is easy, safer and more aesthetically pleasing: depsgraph.object_instances

[image: Instancing in 2.8x]
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API